# What is a mother in her term of breastfeeding called in English?

Tags: word-request

What is a **mother in her period of breastfeeding** called in English?

Based on my guess I looked for "breast-feeder" on Google and indeed I found a documentation of this word in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breastfeeder) but then I checked it in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=breastfeeder) and is missing there. That's why I'm afraid that there is another word for that term. (I'm not talking about the slang Wiktionary mention there: "boobfeeding" but one that I can be written for example in a presentation or a academical book etc.)

N.b. In my native dictionary I found a "**wet nurse**", but according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_nurse) it is *"a wet nurse is a woman who breast feeds and cares for another's child."*. It means that this term is not for the typical woman who breastfeeds **her** baby.

Answer (score 6):

Such a mother can be called a "lactating" mother or, less clinically, a "nursing" mother.

Note NGram distribution for three terms, including yours:

[image]

As you can see, "breast feeder" flatlines, the arc of "lactating mother" suggests a restricted, perhaps technical usage, while "nursing mother" has been much more widely used and for much longer.

Comment: Thank you. Please, put in your answer some links to some dictionaries as follows: 1) [nursing mother in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nursing-mother) 
2) [Nursing in Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nursing)
3) [Nursing mother at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nursing-mother).
Based on google research It seems that "lactating mother" is mainly used in academical works or books in the field of female medicine as a professional jargon. Isn't it?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point Nope. Both terms (lactating and nursing) are pretty widely understood. The room for pumping while at work in my office is called the "lactation facility".

Comment: @subtle_sibling  I agree.  A "nursing mother" is a fairly common term that hardly needs supporting reference.

Comment: Note that if you want to use the term "breastfeed", you can say ["breastfeeding mother" which is slightly more common in print than "lactating mother"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breast-feeding+mother%2Cnursing+mother%2Cbreastfeeding+mother%2Clactating+mother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreast%20-%20feeding%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursing%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreastfeeding%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clactating%20mother%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I would like you to refer to another point. How strange is it to listen to the word "breastfeeder" in lecture, or academical article? Is it more slang?

Comment: No, it's just kind of strange-sounding—bordering on awkward.